# Why is Spring decoding path before matching?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Why does Spring decode path before matching it to controller mappings? E.g. `/foo/%2Fbar/` will match `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar%2Fbaz/` will match `/foo/bar/baz` by default. Intuitively this should be a 404.

This can be disabled by setting

```java
@Configuration
class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

buy why is `urlDecode` set to `true` by default?